# No HTML como aumentar o espaço entre as TDs sem usar cellspacing cellpadding?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, tabela-html

A minha ideia é fazer uma tabela em que tenha um espaçamento entre as células, como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas segundo a documentação da Mozilla por exemplo, é possível confirmar que os atributos `cellspacing=""` `cellpadding=""` estão obsoletos https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

E mesmo se vc falar: *"Está obsoleto, mas ainda funciona!"* Sim de veras funciona, porém da erro no validador da W3C, além de poder parar de funciona em uma atualização do browser no futuro...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero afastar as celular da tabela umas das outras, mas sem o `cellspacing=""` não sei como fazer, já tentei como um `margin: 20px` na `<td>` e mesmo assim não funcionou...

```css
td {
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 6px;
    margin: 20px; /* não funciona */
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>03</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>04</td>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>06</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>07</td>
  <td>08</td>
  <td>09</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

***Como faço para afastar as céluas `<td>` da tabela umas das outras?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar a propriedade **[border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)**, que é equivalente ao velho atributo `cellspacing`. E a vantagem é que o `border-spacing` possui um segundo valor opcional, desta forma podendo definir espaçamentos diferentes na horizontal e vertical.

```
             horizontal
                 ↓
border-spacing: 20px 10px;
                      ↑
                  vertical (opcional)
```

Se o segundo valor for omitido, ambas as direções (horizontal/vertical) terão o mesmo valor:

```
      horizontal e vertical
                 ↓
border-spacing: 20px;
```

> Porém o `border-collapse` da tabela deve estar como `separate`, mas
>   não precisa declará-lo pois esse já é o valor padrão, exceto se tiver alterado  para `collapse`.

**Exemplo:**

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 6px;
}

#tabela { 
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
```

```html
Com border-spacing:
<table id="tabela">
 <tr>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>03</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>04</td>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>06</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>07</td>
  <td>08</td>
  <td>09</td>
 </tr>
</table>

Com cellspacing:
<table cellspacing="20">
 <tr>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>03</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>04</td>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>06</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>07</td>
  <td>08</td>
  <td>09</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: É isso ai, valeu jovem!

Comment: Valeu jovem!...